# Listening for fragment transactions

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to know when fragments(and which fragments) are added/removed/replaced, especially when popped from backstack. I'd like to be notified both before and after the transactions occur, as I sometimes want to delay a transaction for changing an underlaying layout. So in general, I'd like to run some code before and after the transaction plus eventually delay the transaction. I've already thought about using custom animations for that purpose but transactions only accept ids, no objects/classes. And there might be a better solution I currently can't think of. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the fragments for quite a while and if you want something ready out-of-the-box you're out of luck.

The only listener available is the `addOnBackStackChangedListener` and that's it.

But remember that every call that creates and commits a fragment transaction is made by you, either directly via code or indirectly via fragments instantiated on a XML layout or passed to you via the Actionbar tab.
So based on that you should be able to organize your code in some way to always call through a wrapper, but it will be a big work for sure.

Comment: Yeah indeed I call almost all of these transactions myself. With one exception: What about the the backstack? When the backstack has changed(OnBackStackChangedListener) it is already too late.